# Extent report output is not getting generated properly when we Run the scripts using TestNG parallel execution. (Extent Report Version 3.1)

Tags: java, selenium, testng, report, extent

```java
public class ExtentReports_Basecode {

    static Random rand = new Random();
    static long drand = (long)(rand.nextDouble()*10000000000L);

    public WebDriver dr;
    public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static  ExtentTest test;

    private static String filePath = "D://" + drand + "ExtentReports_Bindu.html";

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup()    {

        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(filePath);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows10");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "Bindu");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "rose");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "1234_ws");

        //htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting.in Demo Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Favourite Automation Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startTest(Method m)
    {
        test = extent.createTest(m.getName(),"This is the description of Test" + m.getName());

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public static void getResult(ITestResult result){

        if(result.getStatus()== ITestResult.FAILURE){
            test.log(Status.FAIL,MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test case FAILED due to below issues:",ExtentColor.RED));
            test.fail(result.getThrowable());
        }
        else if(result.getStatus()== ITestResult.SUCCESS){  
            test.log(Status.PASS,MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test Case PASSED",ExtentColor.GREEN));

        }
        else{
            test.log(Status.SKIP,MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test Case Skipped",ExtentColor.YELLOW));
            test.skip(result.getThrowable());
        }

    }


    @AfterSuite
    public void teardown(){
            extent.flush();
    }


}
```

Script1:

```java
public class sc1 extends ExtentReports_Basecode{

    public WebDriver dr;
    public Report report = null;
    String inputSheetPath ="TestData/InputData/DataSheet.xls" ;

    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.out.println("launching Chrome browser"); 
        dr = Driver.getChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    private void sc1_95_Fav(){

        System.out.println("sc1"); }
}
}

Script2:
public class sc2 extends ExtentReports_Basecode{

    public WebDriver dr;
    public Report report = null;
        String inputSheetPath ="TestData/InputData/DataSheet.xls" ;

    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.out.println("launching Chrome browser"); 
        dr = Driver.getChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test
    private void sc2_83_Fav() {

                }
}
}
```

TestNG XML:

```xml
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <!--<suite name="Parallel test Suite">-->
    <suite name="My suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="10">
    <test name="name">

        <classes>
    <!-- To Add Any Class  start -->

         <class name="OpenUI.Favourites.sc1"/> 
         <class name="OpenUI.Favourites.sc2"/>

    <!--To Add Any Class  End -->

    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

in the extent report I m getting results in 2nd test case.. can someone pls suggest where am I missed out and how to see the output properly using extent report parallel testing using TestNG.
[As shown in the image the results output of first Test is shown in the second Test, if any thing get failed the Failed output shown in Last Test not in actual failed Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elKp8.jpg) 
PS: its working fine when I run sequentially one by one using testNG.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this pattern,Hope your problem will be solved

```
WebDriver driver;
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;



        @BeforeTest
        public void setUp() {
            // where we need to generate the report

            htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("Your report Path");
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
            // Set our document title, theme etc..
            htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Rehomes");
            htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Rehomes Production Testing");
            htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
            htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);


                        }
       }
        @Test
        public void HomepageLogo() throws Exception {
            test = extent.createTest("rentalhomesHomePage");
            //Your Test

        }

      @AfterMethod
      public void setTestResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {


          if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
              test.log(Status.FAIL, result.getName());
              test.log(Status.FAIL,result.getThrowable());
              //test.fail("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
          } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
              test.log(Status.PASS, result.getName());
              //test.pass("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
          } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
              test.skip("Test Case : " + result.getName() + " has been skipped");
          }

          extent.flush();
      driver.close();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately the above one dint work and is giving only one test generated as a report if tried in that way. can u suggest any other way to overcome this issue.?

Comment: Please use comments, do not post a comment as an answer